# AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition on xserver 1.20

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers, x-server, amd-graphics

I have Dell Latitude E6540 which has Radeon HD8790M and it runs Debian 10. I wanted to install newest drivers for said video card (becuase games didn't recognize it and I couldn't see it's usage (`radeontop` says `"radeon unknown"` and shows 0% usage on everything)).
So I downloaded [AMD Radeon Software Crimson Edition 15.12 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-8000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-8790m-series-gpu) but when installing it says:

```
error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.20.4_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer 1.20.4_64a:none:4.19.0-5-amd64:)
```

Should I:

install xserver 1.10

install other driver

do something else

?
I can provide more information if required.

Comment: Just a note, it is highly not recommended to installed the proprietary drivers as a blob, outside of the package manager, in order to avoid breaking the system each time and create a [Frankendebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind, my bad. The drivers I already had (`amdgpu` or something) were indeed working, it's just that I didn't tell (e.g.) steam to use my dedicated gpu (by launching it with `DRI_PRIME=1 steam`). And `radeontop` is also working.

Comment: Could you add some details so this question can be helpful to others?